# How to print the selected text inside webview in android

Tags: android, webview

I want to get the selected text inside a `webview` in android application. and print this text .. 
how ? your help is highly appreciated.

### Edit

I mean the text highlighted in the `webview`.

Comment: do you mean to print the text that is highlighted in the top action bar? .. select a text, highlight, then an in-browser action bar appears at the top of the webview. This case?

Answer (score 0):

It may help you.

```
  webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
  {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        // progressBar.show();
        // view.loadUrl(url);

        if (url.startsWith("mailto:") || url.startsWith("tel:")) 
        {

                    int len = url.length();
                    char[] desArray = new char[len - 7];
                    url.getChars(7, len, desArray, 0);
                    String newString1 = new String(desArray);
                    newString1.trim();
                    Log.d("Str", newString1 + "");
                    sendGmail(newString1, 1);
                    return true;
        }
        else 
        {
                    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    }
```

This code is for getting the email Address from webview and getting the phone numbers.